# Jackson Databind from 2.10.2 to 2.13.5 , Replace deprecated method Issue

Tags: java, groovy, dropwizard, jackson-databind

I am upgrading Jackson Databind in my project from 2.10.2 to 2.13.5 in Groovy project.
Due to upgradation there is a problem in deserialisation.
It's found that deprecation of method `getGenericType()` from `AnnotatedParameter` Class and In docs it says to use "`Annotated.getType()` for replacement", But not working.
getGenericType's return type is Type and getType's return type is JavaType.

Although JavaType is type of Type only. Still facing issue in replacing the method.
I am not able to find any implementation example of the replacement.
[Java Doc of Jackson Databind](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/AnnotatedParameter.html#getGenericType--)

For reference, Initially we are using

```
import com.google.inject.Key

def type = Key.get(((AnnotatedMember)m).getGenericType())
value = JacksonInject.Value.forId(type)
```

But when I use getType in place of getGenericType, It's throwing exception

```
ERROR [2023-08-03 11:24:25,060] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: b279e7ec23f219b9
! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a Class, ParameterizedType, or GenericArrayType, but <[simple type, class javax.inject.Provider<java.util.Locale>]> is of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType
! at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.getRawType(MoreTypes.java:209)
! at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.<init>(TypeLiteral.java:84)
! at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.get(TypeLiteral.java:145)
! at com.google.inject.Key.<init>(Key.java:123)
! at com.google.inject.Key.get(Key.java:229)
! at com.google.inject.Key$get$2.call(Unknown Source)
! at mgap.system.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory$3.findInjectableValue(ObjectMapperFactory.groovy:72)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findInjectableValue(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:309)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCandidate.construct(CreatorCandidate.java:32)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addExplicitConstructorCreators(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:450)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:293)
! at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:222)
!
```

*Project Tech* : DropWizard, Groovy, Guice, Jackson

Any reference / lead will be appreciated.

Comment: In your question you mention

It's found that deprecation of method getGenericType() from AnnotatedParameter Class and In docs it says to use "Annotated.getType() for replacement"

However, in your code example I see you cast to AnnotatedMember. I don't know if that creates problems?

Furthermore the stacktrace suggests that the call to Key.get already breaks, which comes before the actual getGenericType call. Might have to do with the cast or it might have to do with a Guice version difference?

Comment: @SilvanVanLeeuwen Thanks for the comment. AnnotatedMember is the base class for AnnotatedParameter. 'm' isInstanceOf AnnotatedParameter. Initially getGenericType was part of AnnotatedParameter. Regarding Key get() method there is Argument of type 'Type'. Still it's throwing IllegalArgumentException . 
My problem is even it's given in docs that getGenericType can be replaced by getType due to deprecation. Still it's not working.